# Why is $x|x|$ differentiable at $0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I understand that the reason $x|x|$ is differentiable at $0 $: if you take the left and right derivative they are equal, in this case $0$. However, what I don't understand is that
$$f'(x) =x^2/|x| + x. $$
If this is the derivative then how can it be defined at $0$, as that would mean we are dividing by $0$ to find the value of $f'(x)$ at $0$?

Comment: You appear to declare what the derivative ought to be and then object when your formula doesn't work.  Just go back to the definition of the derivative, compute the relevant limit.

Comment: Why $\dfrac{x^2}{|x|}+x$ ??

Comment: @yves probably product rule but with the second term wrong.

Comment: This is the result i got when i put into a derivative calculator, i was unable to differentiate it myself

Comment: $x|x|=x\sqrt{x^2}$.  Now use the Leibniz-rule.

Comment: thats really helpful thanks

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $x\lvert x\rvert$ is not $\frac{x^2}{\lvert x\rvert}+x$: it's $2\lvert x\rvert$.

Comment: When i put it into a derivative calculator, this was the answer that came up, so i assumed it was correct

Comment: @Theo It can't be correct. For $x<0,x^2/|x|=-x$ so it returns $0$ derivative, but our function is not constant for $x<0$, right?

Comment: @theo When I put it in mine, I get $2\lvert x\rvert$ ¯\ _(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Symbolically,

$$|x|'=\text{sgn}(x)$$ and is undefined at $x=0$ because the slope is discontinuous.

So for $x\ne0$,

$$(x|x|)'=|x|+x\text{ sgn}(x)=2|x|.$$

The continuation of the derivative at $x=0$ is $0$. (But this is not a proof.)

Answer (score 1):

$$f^\prime(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{(x+h)|x+h|- x|x|}{h}= \left\{ \begin{array}{c} \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} 2x+h, \quad x\ge 0 \\
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{-(x+h)^2+x^2}{h} = -\lim_{h\to0} 2x+h, \quad x< 0
 \end{array} \right. $$

$$f^\prime(x) = 2|x| \quad \text{ and } f^\prime(0) = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

For $ x>0 $, $ f(x)=x^2 $ and $$f'(x)=2x=2|x| $$

For $ x<0 $, $ f(x)=-x^2 $ and $$ f'(x)=-2x=2|x| $$

So, the expression you gave $$f'(x)=\frac{x^2}{x}+x=\frac{|x|^2}{|x|}+x=|x|+x$$
Is not correct.